# Derivative of an Integral in a Domain of Constant Size

Tags: integration, fluid-dynamics

I have the following integral that represents the fluid's mass change in a tank with volume $V$ over time.$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_V\rho dV$$

- $\rho$ is the mass density of the fluid
- $dV$ is a differential volume within the tank

I know that

1. the density can be treated as a continuous function within the tank, and
2. that the volume of the tank is constant.

**Based on #1**$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_V\rho dV=\int_V\frac{d\rho}{dt}dV$$
**Based on #2**$$\int_V\frac{d\rho}{dt}dV=\frac{d\rho}{dt}V$$

How do I verify/explain the second step?

Comment: The second one is true only if $\frac{d \rho}{d t}$ is constant over the whole domain $V$, and is definitely not true in general. Note also that your notation is highly confusing. You use $V$ to denote the domain, the volume of the domain, and the measure you are integrating with respect to.

Comment: Any fluid mechanics text will use a similar notation.

Comment: Perhaps for the differential volume. But they wouldn't say $\int_V dV = V$. That doesn't make sense. Imagine saying $\int_{(0,1)} d x = (0,1)$. It is simply wrong. What they might say is $\int_V dV = |V|$ or something like it where the RHS denotes the volume of the domain $V$.

Comment: To be more clear, in #2 when you use $V$ in the subscript of the integral, it is a set. But when you use it on the RHS, it is a number. This doesn't make sense

Comment: In this case, it is referring to the control volume which is identical with the fixed volume of the tank. Most textbooks will at one point or another using a more general definition $\int_{C.V.}\phi dV$ and later in the example might change C.V. to V.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted what I have said. It is not the issue of using $V$ to denote the domain over which you integrate. Let us say that this domain is $V=(0,1)^3$ (the unit box). Let us suppose that $\frac{d \rho}{d t}$ is constant over the domain $V$. Writing #2 replacing $V$ with its explicit definition yields $\int_{(0,1)^3} \frac{d \rho}{dt} dV = \frac{d \rho}{dt} (0,1)^3$. This is certainly not true and doesn't make sense as the RHS is a set. What is true is $\int_{(0,1)^3} \frac{d \rho}{dt} dV = \frac{d \rho}{dt}$ because $1 = |(0,1)^3|$ is the volume of the domain.

Comment: @epiliam, sorry for any confusion. I think I understand what you're saying just fine. I probably just communicated it poorly. Think of C.V. as a set of all points within volume V.  The issue is probably just lazy notation e.g., $\int_a^x x^2 dx=\frac{x^3-a^3}{3}$.

Comment: What I was suggesting was that you edit the question so that the part after "Based on #2" reads: $\int_V \frac{d \rho}{dt} dV = \frac{d \rho}{dt} |V|$. However, I think your original question is more or less answered in the first line of my first comment.

Comment: It is better to leave the question as is, since that is how the book explains it.